# Creating Windows Service and batch file

Tags: c++, windows, windows-services

I want to create windows service which will run batch file upon start.
I am aware of API's like `createservice` , but what i want is when I say `Start service` from `Service Control Manager` I want to invoke my batch file with parameter `start` and when I say stop I want to invoke same batch file with `stop` parameter

Comment: What are you finding hard? Do you know how to execute batch files by calling `ShellExecute`? Do you know how to respond to a service start? Do you know how to write a service?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do any windows service action like, start/stop/pause service, the service main controller handler function which you have registered through RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(), receives messages like SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE, SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP etc...

You can create separate functions to invoke the bat file with different input parameters and those functions can be called when appropriate service messages are received.

void ServiceMainCntrlHandler(unsigned long request)
{ 
  switch(request) 
  { 
    /* Received service pause signal */
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE: 
      // Change the service current status to pause
      ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState  = SERVICE_PAUSED;
      SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus);

```
  // TODO: Call appropriate function
  break;

/* Received service continue signal */
case SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE:
  // Change the service current status to started
  ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState  = SERVICE_RUNNING;
  SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus);

  // TODO: Call appropriate function
  break;

/* Received service stop signal */
case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
  // Change the service current status to stopped
  ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
  ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState  = SERVICE_STOPPED;
  ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint        = 0;
  ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint      = 0;
  SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus);

  // TODO: Call the function which will invoke the bat file with input parameter as "stop"
  break;         
default:  break;
```

}
}